# How can i ignore case when using lambda expression in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a lambda expression as follows:

```
 var obj = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id && x.city == city.ToLower());
```

data is a List

how can i make it so i ignore case ?

Comment: is it for [tag:entity-framework] or POCO? you could try `String.Equals` and set the second parameter to ignore case as shown in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings#case-insensitive-ordinal-comparisons). the `String.Equals` and `String.Compare` should be covered in ef as far as i remember, but some dbms may behave differently (and yes, take caution of encoding and collation if any).

Comment: also, calling `ToLower()` on both `String`s can also do wonder for ascii. just lower that `x.city` like `x.city.ToLower()`.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with lambda expressions. It's just a string comparison. You would make it case-insensitive the same way you would any other string comparison. You could find out how to do that with a simple web search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id.Equals(id, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && x.city.Equals(city, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

In c#, string.Equals compares the content of the strings, ensuring they have the same characters but == operator checks if the references of the string point to the same memory location. Therefore, string.Equals is a preferable solution to compare strings.

In this specific case ,I am using Equals(String, StringComparison) overload method to compare string with StringComparison parameter which is an Enum. StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase compares strings using culture-sensitive sort rules, the invariant culture, and ignoring the case of the strings being compared.

This is a better solution if you work with culture-agnostic data.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. Please provide a bit more explanation to help readers.

Answer (score 6):

[String.Equals(String, StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-8.0#system-string-equals(system-string-system-stringcomparison)) is the generally preferred approach:

```
var obj = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id 
    && x.city.Equals(city, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

However if your lambda is going to be interpreted as an expression tree, as in the case of EF to SQL, then *StringComparison* may not be supported or may not be necessary.

In scenarios where *StringComparison* is not supported, you could perform `.ToLower()` on both operands:

```
var obj = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id 
    && x.city.ToLower() == city.ToLower());
```

Be aware however that this executes the function on both operands, in expression trees this might have performance implications, for EF to SQL scenarios you should consider using a case insensitive collation instead of converting the column values to make use of indexes on the affected columns.

> **Notes to Callers of [String.ToLower()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=net-8.0)**
> As explained in [Best Practices for Using Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings), we recommend that you avoid calling string casing methods that substitute default values and instead call methods that require parameters to be explicitly specified. To convert a character to lowercase by using the casing conventions of the current culture, signal your intention explicitly by calling the [ToLower(CultureInfo)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=net-8.0#system-string-tolower(system-globalization-cultureinfo)) method overload with a value of [CurrentCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-8.0#system-globalization-cultureinfo-currentculture) for its culture parameter. If you don't need linguistic-aware comparison, consider using [Ordinal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=net-8.0#system-stringcomparison-ordinal).